# Add Icons to nodes in Sankey Chart implemented through React Google Charts Package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-visualization, sankey-diagram

I've used React Google Charts Package to implement Sankey graph in the project.

However I want to add custom icons to the nodes in the sankey graph. I've looked over the documentation google charts API and package documentation however no luck.

If anyone could guide on how to add custom icons to sankey graph through google charts, that would be really nice.

https://www.react-google-charts.com/
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: see [overlays](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/overlays)...